# How to call a function on the scope from a string value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have an object containing an array of strings

```
$scope.actions=[
    "add_inscription",
    "add_tools",
    "add_instruction",
    "remove_inscription",
    "remove_tools",
    "remove_instruction"
];
```

and I would like to be able to do dynamic action calls through a delegating function..

```
$scope.delegate = function () {

    var arg = arguments[0];

    for ( key in $scope.actions ) {

        if ($scope.actions[key] == arg ) {

            // call function that has a matching name

        }
    }
}
```

So in my template I have something like this

```
<button ng-click="delegate('add_inscription')">Add Inscription</button>
```

I don't know if I am thinking in the right direction with this either,, but the point is that my actions object is actually pretty large and I don't want to write massive switch case statement that I will have to update all the time.

**Is there a way to do this in angular?**

I have no problem doing this in **straight up javascript**

```
var fnstring = "add_inscription";

// find object
var fn = window[fnstring];

// if object is a function
if (typeof fn === "function") fn();
```

but in angular I can't get this done..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that your "actions" functions are defined inside the scope, like:

```
$scope.add_inscription = function(){ ... }
```

you should do:

```
var _action = 'add_inscription';
$scope[_action]();
```

Comment: OMG,, I can't believe this,,, I kept trying that,, and I already used this in the past but I completely forgot to append () to the $scope['add_inscription'],,, thanks for that. I must be exhausted if I can't see something trivial like that. I am actually asigning the function name to a scope variable.